# React list element disappears in grandchild component when grandparent state is updated. Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have created a functional component which belongs to the sidebard. It contains of 3 components.

**ProductFilters** - main list component, fetches possible data filters from the server, provides a filters state which can be updated by child components when a filter is selected.

**FilterOptions** - filter category

**Option** - represents each option in filter menu. When is selected, it calls **ProductFilters** callback to update the filters list. After selecting it, the `filters` map is being updated and... the selected `Option` element dissapears. After selecting the empty place, react throws and error

> index.js:1 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
> Check the render method of `FilterOptions`

Each `Option` element has it's own unique key which is the option name. What might be the issue?

Here is my code:

```
import axios from "axios";
import List from "@mui/material/List";
import ListItemButton from "@mui/material/ListItemButton";
import ListItemIcon from "@mui/material/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@mui/material/ListItemText";
import Collapse from "@mui/material/Collapse";
import InboxIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MoveToInbox";
import ExpandLess from "@mui/icons-material/ExpandLess";
import ExpandMore from "@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";

const Option = (props) => {
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);
    const handleClick = () => {
        setSelected(!selected);
        props.setFilter(props.category, props.name, !selected);
    };

    return (
        <ListItemButton
            selected={selected}
            sx={{ pl: 8 }}
            onClick={handleClick}
        >
            <ListItemText primary={props.name} />
        </ListItemButton>
    );
};

const FilterOptions = (props) => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const handleClick = () => {
        setOpen(!open);
    };

    const displayOptions = () => {
        const options = [];
        for (const [key, option] of props.filter) {
            options.push(
                <Option
                    key={key}
                    name={option.name}
                    category={props.name}
                    setFilter={props.setFilter}
                />
            );
        }
        return options;
    };
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <ListItemButton sx={{ pl: 4, fontSize: 12 }} onClick={handleClick}>
                <ListItemText primary={props.name} />
            </ListItemButton>
            <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                <List component="div" disablePadding>
                    {displayOptions()}
                </List>
            </Collapse>
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default function ProductFilters(props) {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [filters, setFilters] = useState(new Map());

    const setFilter = (category, filter, selected) => {
        const options = filters.get(category).set(filter, selected);
        setFilters(new Map(filters.set(category, options)));
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchFilters = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await axios.get(
                    `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/product/filters`
                );
                const outputFilters = new Map();
                res.data.map((filter) => {
                    const options = new Map();
                    filter.taxonomydata_set.map((option) => {
                        options.set(option.name, {
                            name: option.name,
                            selected: false,
                        });
                    });
                    outputFilters.set(filter.category, options);
                });
                setFilters(outputFilters);
            } catch (err) {}
        };

        fetchFilters();
    }, []);

    const handleClick = () => {
        setOpen(!open);
    };

    const displayFilters = () => {
        let filterList = [];

        for (const [categoryName, filterCat] of filters) {
            filterList.push(
                <FilterOptions
                    key={categoryName}
                    name={categoryName}
                    filter={filterCat}
                    setFilter={setFilter}
                />
            );
        }

        return filterList;
    };

    const handleApplyFilters = () => {
        console.log(filters);
    };

    return (
        <List
            sx={{
                width: "100%",
                maxWidth: 260,
                bgcolor: "background.paper",
            }}
            component="nav"
            aria-labelledby="nested-list-subheader"
        >
            <ListItemButton onClick={handleClick}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                    <InboxIcon />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={props.ListTitle} />
                {open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
            </ListItemButton>
            <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                <List>{displayFilters()}</List>
            </Collapse>
            <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleApplyFilters}>
                Apply filters
            </Button>
        </List>
    );
}
```

[Link to the code on codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-booth-lfi7t)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should apply the 'key' to the Fragment

```
const Option = (props) => {
  ...

    return (
        <ListItemButton
            key={props.name}
            selected={selected}
            sx={{ pl: 8 }}
            onClick={handleClick}
        >
            <ListItemText primary={props.name} />
        </ListItemButton>
    );
};

const FilterOptions = (props) => {
    ....
    return (
        <Fragment key={props.name}>
            ...
        </Fragment>
    );
}
```

Comment: Each FilterOptions component is generated in ```displayFilters``` function where the key is assigned. In every place I generate a list of components, I add the corresponding key. I tried like you suggested but the result remains the same.

Comment: @MichalMajeran could you check the key on Option too

Comment: I tried but still the same. Basically I already set the keys in loops. There is no way that any ```{props.name}``` is not unique. Somehow the problem occurs when the ```setFilter ``` callback is called from child in ```handleClick```

Comment: I can't see the error, could you share a codesanbox or similar?

Comment: I have changed the axios call to stub data, please check the code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-booth-lfi7t

Comment: Thank for your support. Please check out my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69860085/17337527

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved.** The issue wasn't the keys, they were set correctly.
The problem was in handler function. I had overwrite the map element type from JSON to boolean (**selected**) which caused that my `Option` component was not keyed anymore with props.name during re-render because the name was removed and replaced by boolean variable.

From:

```
    const setFilter = (category, filter, selected) => {
        const options = filters.get(category).set(filter, selected);
        setFilters(new Map(filters.set(category, options)));
    };
```

changed to

```
    const setFilter = (category, filter, selected) => {
        const option = filters.get(category).get(filter);
        option.selected = selected;
        const options = filters.get(category).set(filter, option);
        setFilters(new Map(filters.set(category, options)));
    };
```